# emacs-24: solid-colored mode-line with my color choice?

Tags: mode-line, coloring

Is it possible in emacs-24 to set up a solid-colored mode-line with my color choice? ... for example, the entire mode-line would have a red background, and all mode-line text fields would be in foreground white?

I used to be able to do this in emacs-23 via color-theme.el, but now, all the "modeline*" settings that color-theme uses only seem to affect the buffer-name portion of the mode-line, and not that entire line.

Am I out of luck in emacs-24, or is there some way to color the entire mode line?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This blog was very useful to me when I started learning how to configure the `mode-line-format`:  http://amitp.blogspot.com/2011/08/emacs-custom-mode-line.html  It's a little more complicated than just selecting a theme or pressing a button.  Various components can have different foreground/background faces, and there are also the active/inactive faces.

Comment: Thank you. I have checked out that blog and now, I have re-read it. This describes how to set the attributes for the individual components (buffer name, etc.); however, it doesn't describe how to set the background of the entire mode line. Are there any docs for how to do _this_ in emacs-24?

Comment: There are only two faces that control overall background and foreground color:  `M-x customize-face RET mode-line RET` and `M-x customize-face RET mode-line-inactive RET`   Setting those two faces will not override individual components that have a specific color, but they will affect general text that does not have a face specifically assigned.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to lawlist, I now know that the answer to my question is this:
set the attributes for the faces "mode-line" and "mode-line-inactive".

Comment: Could you please edit your post to make it self-contained?  For example, it would help others if you could post the actual code you used to address the problem.